# I want to display a list of names(3) from a textbox(user input) into a label

Tags: vb.net

This is the code I have so far but is not working properly. The textbox for the names user should input and the button show to display the names in a label in the order entered.

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim intcount, w1, w2, w3 As Integer
    Dim intMax As Integer = 2

    For intcount = 0 To intMax
        strSurnames(intcount) = TextBox1.Text

    Next
    TextBox1.Clear()

End Sub

Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click 
    Dim intMax As Integer = 2 
    For intcount = 0 To intMax
        lblShow.Text &= strSurnames(intcount)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How many textboxes are there? Only 1 or 3?

Comment: Where and how is `strSurnames` declared?

Comment: Gosh, **please** drop the Hungarian Notation. This is VB.NET, not COBOL.

Comment: i need to use only one textbox    ' Private strSurnames(2) As String'

Comment: Your post is missing a lot of details.  If there is one TextBox, how are you getting multiple user names?  How are you controlling the entry to only three?  intMax probably shouldn't be a local variable in your Add event.  Best to use a `List(of String)` instead of that array.  If you look at your code, all the items in your array are getting the same information that's in the TextBox1 control.

Comment: Is it a `Multiline` TextBox?

Comment: well i don't understand the question quite well.. the question asks to create a program to store 20 surnames with their respective total weight so the data will be stored in two separate arrays one for the surnames and one for the totals. once the arrays are full the textboxes and the add button should be disabled and the show button should be enabled,, when pressed to display the result in a label on the order entered

Comment: @Mat'sMug `Gosh, please drop the Hungarian Notation. This is VB.NET, not COBOL` what is wrong with Hungarian if I may ask, can you give a credible reason ***to drop the notation***? I did not know it was an issue rather just a convention if I am correct. It is widely accepted and followed in many languages actually, not any particular one... Just my thoughts and waiting your response.

Comment: @Zaggler that's been thoroughly dissected several times before. [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/102690/68834) for instance. Joel's blog post is particularly enlightening.

Comment: @Mat's Mug I don't want someone else's thought, yours as Im interested to know why. It is a notation correct? Every business is different in terms of conventions, many factors per say. Notation aids in a process or method of noting or setting down by means of a special system of signs or symbols, this doesn't mean anything specific... Its still a very debatable subject, but it never changes anything as there is no difference between theory and practice.

Comment: @Zaggler I kill Hungarian Notation wherever I see it, for all the reasons in that post, and because it's useless clutter that makes code harder to read than it needs to be. Take `strSurnames` here, the variable is an **array** of strings. Or possibly a generic `List`, or just any `IEnumerable(Of String)`. What's `str` buying the OP? Isn't `surnames` simpler and more meaningful? Why would `count` be anything other than an `int`? And if it had to be an `Int64` for some reason, would it be a different prefix? Variables should be named after what they're used for, not their type.

Comment: @Mat'sMug thank you for your thought's, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are going to use only 1 textbox and click the "add button" multiple times to store the name. If this is true, you will first need to create

```
Dim arrayStr As New List(Of String)
```

Every single time you click on the add button, it will add into this array.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        arrayStr.Add(TextBox1.Text.Trim())
        TextBox1.Clear()
End Sub
```

And to show the full name in just one label when you click on the "Show button", can do it like this

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Label1.Text = "" //The label text is cleared.
        For i As Integer = 0 To arrayStr.Count() - 1
            Label1.Text += arrayStr(i) + ", "
        Next
    End Sub
```

**UPDATE - BASED ON YOUR COMMENT QUESTION**
This is the updated solution based on your question. I am only going to show you with the "Sur Names" only. You can implement the "Weight" the same way.

First, create your array and declare a count as integer for the size of your array.

```
Dim surNameStr(20) As String
Dim count As Integer = 0
```

In the "Add Button", you increase the count number by 1 every time you add a new sur name. Once it reached your "maximum" number, you disable your button by `BtnAdd.Enabled = False`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If count < 20 Then
            surNameStr(count) = TextBox1.Text.Trim()
            count = count + 1
        Else
            Button1.Enabled = False
            Button2.Enabled = True
        End If
End Sub
```

Then, in "Show Button", this is how you can show all the surnames stored.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Label1.Text = ""
        For i As Integer = 0 To 19
            Label1.Text += surNameStr(i) + vbNewLine
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @EdMata Just read your comment in your question. Check out the Edited answer. :)